# Target non-unique HTML element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I want to apply a JS fade-in/out to an HTML element that has no unique ID or class.

```html
<div class="view-content">
      <table class="views-view-grid cols-3">

  <tbody>
          <tr class="row-1 row-first row-last">
                  <td class="col-1 col-first views-portals-row">

  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <h1 class="field-content view_portals_title"><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/hydrography">Hydrography</a></h1>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-attribution">        <div class="field-content view_portals_attr" style="display: none;"></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-portal">        <div class="field-content view_portals_img"><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/hydrography"><img width="261" height="200" alt="" src="http://dev.test.eu/sites/test.eu/files/public/hydrography.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image"></a></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-body">        <div class="field-content view_portals_desc"><p>Data on bathymetry&nbsp;(water depth), coastlines, and geographical location of underwater features:&nbsp;wrecks.</p>
<p><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/hydrography" class="button small">Read more</a></p>
</div>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-2 views-portals-row">

  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <h1 class="field-content view_portals_title"><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/geology">Geology</a></h1>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-attribution">        <div class="field-content view_portals_attr" style="display: none;"></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-portal">        <div class="field-content view_portals_img"><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/geology"><img width="299" height="200" alt="" src="http://dev.test.eu/sites/test.eu/files/public/geology.png" typeof="foaf:Image"></a></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-body">        <div class="field-content view_portals_desc"><p>Data on seabed substrate, sea-floor geology, coastal behaviour, geological events and probabilities, and minerals.</p>
<p><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/geology" class="button small">Read more</a></p>
</div>  </div>          </td>
                  <td class="col-3 col-last views-portals-row">

  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <h1 class="field-content view_portals_title"><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/seabed-habitats-0">Seabed Habitats</a></h1>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-attribution">        <div class="field-content view_portals_attr" style="display: none;">Posidonia oceanica, &copy; David Balata</div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-portal">        <div class="field-content view_portals_img"><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/seabed-habitats-0"><img width="267" height="200" alt="" src="http://dev.test.eu/sites/test.eu/files/public/Posidonia%20oceanica_2.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image"></a></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-body">        <div class="field-content view_portals_desc"><p>Data on modelled seabed habitats based on seadbed substrate, energy , biological zone, and&nbsp;salinity.</p>
<p><a href="http://dev.test.eu/content/seabed-habitats-0" class="button small">Read more</a></p>
</div>  </div>          </td>
              </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
```

I use the following script to hide and show the attribution of a picture:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.view_portals_attr').hide();
      $('.views-portals-row').hover(function() {
        $('.view_portals_attr').fadeIn();
      }, function() {
        $('.view_portals_attr').fadeOut();
      });
    });      
})(jQuery);
```

The problem is that all attributions are shown when hovering over any picture in the list. Can someone give me a clue how to target one at a time?

Comment: why don't you add a class so you can use that on yout jQuery?
like 'js_portals_hover' or anything like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to select only the children, something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.view_portals_attr').hide();
      $('.views-portals-row').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.view_portals_attr').fadeIn();
      }, function() {
        $(this).find('.view_portals_attr').fadeOut();
      });
    });      
})(jQuery);
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SVxKx/

Comment: [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) selects only direct children matching that selector, while [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) selects any matching descendant. Only `.find()` will work with the [given HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18594893/578288), and `.find()` is also more future-proof.

Comment: Corrected the example - with that feedback.